# Mobile security and vulnerability analysis tool

Tags: android, ios, security, mobile

What tools should I use to test the security of my iOS application?

What are the open source tools available to make vulnerability assessment of an iOS and Android application?

Any online tool which can discover security vulnerabilities of the iOS and Android application?

I got Veracode and appVigil.io but I want some alternatives to them.

Comment: I've not tried such an app myself, but for Android there's e.g. the [Vulnerability Test Suite](http://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.nowsecure.android.vts) meeting your requirements. No idea for iOS, though.

Comment: Why do you need alternatives? What’s wrong with the mentioned tools? -- Should the solutions run on the mobile devices, or can/should they run from your desktop PC? If yes, which operating system?